# cannot bind to new constructor function

Tags: javascript, this

the following code will throw an type error for the name property:
Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function.
I expect to get user name 'Unknown'
I get this result if i use bind like:

```js
const User = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

function userMsg(msg) {
  this.name = this.name || 'Unknown'
  return `${this.name} said: ${msg}`
}

const newMsg = userMsg.bind(User)
newMsg('say smth')
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why are you trying to bind to a constructor function? The constructor shouldn't have a `name` property, it should assign on to the instance of `User` when it is called to create an instance (which you never do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is trying to use the `User` constructor function as `this` inside `userMsg`. That causes the problem that you are executing `userMsg` in the context of a `function`. Functions have a read-only property `name` which you cannot overwrite, which comes from `Function.prototype.name`.

Luckily, that is not what you want to do anyway. If you instead of binding the `User` function bind an **instance** created by calling the contructor function, you can stick to your property `name`:

```js
const User = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

function userMsg(msg) {
  this.name = this.name || 'Unknown'
  return `${this.name} said: ${msg}`
}

const max = new User('Max'); // you need a User instance to bind to
const newMsg = userMsg.bind(max); // bind it here

console.log(newMsg('say smth'));
```

In actual use, you probably also don't want to use `bind`, but rather add `userMsg` to the `User.prototype`:

```js
const User = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

User.prototype.userMsg = function(msg) {
  return `${this.name} says: ${msg}`
}

const max = new User('Max');
const newMsg = max.userMsg('Hello!'); // now we can call the function on the user

console.log(newMsg);
```

or at least, don't `bind` it permanently, but rather use `call` to use the user context once:

```js
const User = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

function userMsg(msg) {
  this.name = this.name || 'Unknown'
  return `${this.name} said: ${msg}`
}

const max = new User('Max');
const newMsg = userMsg.call(max, 'say smth'); // use call to set context only for this call

console.log(newMsg);
```